# Path name with dot-colon on Windows creates a ghost file

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I do not understand this behavior. This is a minimal reproduction of a strange behavior I discovered while trying to write to a file whose name is an ISO format time string including `:`. The file name was truncated starting with `:`.

The colon is an invalid path character on Windows when not part of a drive name.

However, this command on cmd:

```
echo hello >x.:x
```

Creates a file that shows up on `dir` as `x.`. `Path().iterdir()` in Python also lists `x.`.

However, `x.` is not readable in cmd, and neither is `x.:x`:

```
C:\Users\user>dir x*
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F606-918D

 Directory of C:\Users\user

05/09/2023  01:59                 0 x.
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)   6,182,993,920 bytes free

C:\Users\user>type x.
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\user>type x.:x
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Though it is readable in Python:

```
In [1]: Path('x.:x').read_text()
Out[1]: 'hello \n'
```

I would expect Windows to reject a file name like this, whether on cmd or Python, just like it rejects `x:x` with `The system cannot find the path specified` or `FileNotFoundError`. However, the dot-colon escapes error for some reason.

I am on Windows 10 and My Python `sys.version` is `'3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:58:39) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]'`

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: I only know it has something to do with "alternate data streams". A NTFS file can hold multiple content streams. The name of the ADS is written after the file name, divided by a colon. Due to the drive letter notation with colon this may lead to ambiguities.

Comment: You say you create `x:.x`, but later you are reading from `x.:x`. What is it? (Hint: try `dir /R`)

Comment: @Stephan thanks for the catch, it's a typo. The correct is `x.:x`. It is impossible to write to `x:.x`, yielding `The system cannot find the path specified`.

Comment: ... except you happen to have an `X:\` drive.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, I think this is it. The truncated part of the filename really did turn into a data stream in the case of the time strings. In the case of `x.:x`, perhaps the requirement of a file not ending with a dot is missed when writing to a data stream. This seems like a bug. I'll try to report it to Microsoft, although I doubt they will fix it. You can compose an answer for me to accept if you'd like

Comment: Thank you but I would want to give a complete answer but I can't as the alternate data streams are only one partial explanation of the mysterious behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is in fact written to an ADS (alternate data stream)
You can read your text using `notepad x.:x` or directly print out the attached stream with `more < x.:x`

What you do is write the text 'hello' to an ADS named 'x' that is attached to a file called 'x.'